# What is the cleanest way to listen to JMS from inside a Spring-batch step?

Tags: activemq-classic, spring-batch, spring-jms

Spring batch documentation recommends using the JmsItemReader, which is a wrapper around the JMSTemplate.  However, I have discovered that the JMSTemplate has some issues - see http://activemq.apache.org/jmstemplate-gotchas.html .

This post came to my attention only because the queue was appearing to disappear before I could actually read the data of of it.  The opportunity to miss messages seems like a fairly significant issue to me.

Comment: It looks to me like http://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518086/spring-batch-not-all-records-are-being-processed-from-mq-retrieval?rq=1 is related, since the symptom he reported is exactly the symptom that the apache post describes

Answer (score 0):

For consumers atleast try using DefaultMessageListenerContainer coupled with a SingleConnectionFactory or any such connection factory , it not need a scheduler to wake them up.there are log of examples explaining this , this one is really good in explaining stuff
http://bsnyderblog.blogspot.com/2010/05/tuning-jms-message-consumption-in.html

Comment: Thanks for the feedback. Since the JMSTemplate is guaranteed to lose messages in this context, no solution involving a JMSTemplate is a viable answer.  I won't downgrade this answer because I may still be missing something.

Answer (score 0):

Here is the solution I ended up with.  Since the query was about the "cleanest" way to listen to JMS from within a spring-batch step, I'm  going to leave the question open for a while longer just in case there's a better way.

If someone can figure out why the code isn't formatting correctly, please let me know how to fix it.

**1. In the a job listener, implement queue setup and teardown inside the beforeJob and afterJob events, respectively:**

```
public void beforeJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    try {
        jobParameters = jobExecution.getJobParameters();

        readerConnection = connectionFactory.createConnection();
        readerConnection.start();

    } catch (JMSException ex) {
        // handle the exception as appropriate
    }
}

public void afterJob(JobExecution jobExecution) {
    try {
        readerConnection.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // handle the exception as appropriate
    }
}
```

**2. In the reader, implement the StepListener and beforeStep / afterStep methods.**

```
public void beforeStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    this.stepExecution = stepExecution;
    this.setJobExecution(stepExecution.getJobExecution());
    try {
        this.connection = jmsJobExecutionListener.getReaderConnection();
        this.jmsSession = connection.createSession(false, Session.AUTO_ACKNOWLEDGE);
        this.messageConsumer = jmsSession.createConsumer(jmsJobExecutionListener.getQueue());
    }
    catch (JMSException ex)
    {
        // handle the exception as appropriate
    }

}

public ExitStatus afterStep(StepExecution stepExecution) {
    try {
        messageConsumer.close();
        jmsSession.close();
    } catch (JMSException e) {
        // handle the exception as appropriate
    }
    return stepExecution.getExitStatus();
}
```

**3. Implement the read() method:**

```
public TreeModel<SelectedDataElementNode> read() throws Exception,
        UnexpectedInputException, ParseException,
        NonTransientResourceException {

    Object result = null;

    logger.debug("Attempting to receive message on connection: ", connection.toString());

    ObjectMessage msg = (ObjectMessage) messageConsumer.receive();
    logger.debug("Received: {}", msg.toString());

    result = msg.getObject();
    return result;
}
```

**4. Add the listeners to the Spring Batch context as appropriate:**

```
<batch:job id="doStuff">
    <batch:listeners>
        <batch:listener ref="jmsJobExecutionListener" />
    </batch:listeners>
... snip ...
            <batch:step id="step0003-do-stuff">
                <batch:tasklet transaction-manager="jtaTransactionManager"
                    start-limit="100">
                    <batch:chunk reader="selectedDataJmsReader" writer="someWriter"
                        commit-interval="1" />
                </batch:tasklet>
                <batch:listeners>
                    <batch:listener ref="selectedDataJmsReader" />
                </batch:listeners>
            </batch:step>
</batch:job>
```